# Query XML data in a function with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, sql-server-2012, xquery

I am facing problems while retrieving data from XML.

```
with xmlnamespaces ('x-elements' as x)
select 
tb.[Profile].value('(x:ppr/x:static/refId)[1]', 'varchar(22)') testCol
from table1 tb
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But, when I pass the XML path in a function it compiles correctly but doesn't return data upon calling but just the xml path (that is passed to it).

```
CREATE FUNCTION testFunc
(
    @p varchar(22)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rs nvarchar(max);
    with xmlnamespaces ('x-elements' as x)
    select 
        @Rs = tb.[Profile].value('(sql:variable("@p_path"))[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
    from table1 tb
    RETURN (@Rs)

END
```

The result I am getting is "x:ppr/x:sta" (which is a path not the value) whereas it should return a value like "aJxk9pGntc5V"
Please suggest a solution!

Comment: **SHOW US** the XML ! And also: **WHAT** error do you get? We can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Comment: I replaced with this and now error gone but its not fetching correct value but just the path
@Rs = tb.[Profile].value('(sql:variable("@p_path"))[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

Comment: Please see the updated code. Now I am not getting error but the value returned is not correct as it just returns the xml path that has been passed to this function.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to the `value()` function has to be a string literal. You can not replace it with a variable/parameter that contains the XQuery you want to execute.

From [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

**Syntax**

> value (XQuery, SQLType)

**XQuery**

> Is the XQuery expression, a string literal, that retrieves data
>   inside the XML instance.

Your attempt to use `sql:variable("@p_path")` will insert the value of `@p_path` as a string to the XQuery. It will not replace the entire XQuery expression. It will translate to something like `value('("x:ppr/x:sta")', 'varchar(100)')`

Comment: @talaa123 You can't. One option is to build the entire query dynamically and use `sp_executesql` but that is not allowed in a function.

Comment: But there must be a work around to deal it. Any other method to retrieve value?