# SQL XML Query with xpath defined in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract some data from XML using SQL Query, i am getting values as nulls(for query 3) if XPath defined in a table is to query the xml value. Here is the example. Mikeal Eriksson and TT suggested me to use dynamic query, but how come query 1 is working with out dynamic sql.

```
 DECLARE @StudentData XML
SET @StudentData =N'<StudentData>
  <Properties>
    <Property>
      <Name>RollNumber</Name>
      <Value>2127</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>SudentName</Name>
      <Value>ABCD</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>Subject1</Name>
      <Value>80</Value>
    </Property>
    </Properties>
</StudentData>';
CREATE TABLE #PropertyPath (    
    XPath VARCHAR (2000)   NOT NULL,    
    Id INT NOT NULL       
);

INSERT INTO #PropertyPath
SELECT 'RollNumber',1
UNION 
SELECT 'SudentName',2
UNION 
SELECT 'Name',3

CREATE TABLE #Property (    
    StudentData XML NOT NULL,
    RefId INT NOT NULL       
);

INSERT INTO #Property
SELECT @StudentData,3

INSERT INTO #Property
SELECT @StudentData,1

--Query 1
SELECT A.StudentData.value('(/StudentData/Properties/Property/*[local-name()=sql:column("XPath")])[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),XPath FROM #Property A
INNER JOIN #PropertyPath B
ON A.RefId =B.Id

--Query 2
SELECT @StudentData.value('(/StudentData/Properties/Property[Name=''RollNumber'']/Value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)')

--Query 3
SELECT A.StudentData.value('(/StudentData/Properties/Property[Name=''[local-name()=sql:column("XPath")]'']/Value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),XPath FROM #Property A
INNER JOIN #PropertyPath B
ON A.RefId =B.Id

DROP TABLE #PropertyPath
DROP TABLE #Property
```

Am i doing anything wrong or is it not possible?

Comment: why not this 

SELECT 
x.i.value('./Name[1]','VARCHAR(20)'),
x.i.value('./Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @StudentData.nodes('/StudentData/Properties/Property') AS x(i)

Comment: @Rishabh: I have a requirement where XPath needs to be configured and not written in SQL directly

Comment: What issue? Please be as detailed as possible. Refer to the [StackOverflow Posting Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TT. Sorry,Edited the post with the issue.

Comment: [This answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25684914/569436).

Comment: I think in short what @MikaelEriksson is saying, you will have to build the SQL in a VARCHAR and use sp_executesql/EXECUTE to get proper behaviour. Ie what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Can i use query instead of value method? I am ok to change my XPath configured to make it work for query instead of value method

Comment: @SandeepPolavarapu Reading the docu both value() and query() expect a XQuery in string form, so I suspect the result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks @MikaelEriksson, Will try the dynamic

Comment: @MikaelEriksson i updated the question with the example with out dynamic query, can you have a look at it and suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how come query 1 is working with out dynamic sql.

The predicate in the XQuery is true for node names equal to the value in column `XPath`. `sql:column()` is used to extract the value from a column. `local-name()` returns the current node name. Row three in `#PropertyPath` has the value `Name` which means that you get the value `RollNumber` returned for the match on `Name` and `NULL` returned for `RollNumber` XPath because there is no node in the XML named `RollNumber`.

> I am getting values as nulls(for query 3)

In query 3 you are comparing the value of a node `Name` with the string `[local-name()=sql:column("XPath")]` and since there are no nodes in the XML with the value `[local-name()=sql:column("XPath")]` you get `NULL` as a result.

Update:

To get the values where you have a match on name you can use this:

```sql
SELECT A.StudentData.value('(/StudentData/Properties/Property[(Name/text())[1] = sql:column("XPath")]/Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
       XPath 
FROM #Property A
INNER JOIN #PropertyPath B
ON A.RefId =B.Id
```

Comment: Ok, i was wrongly understood local-name() function. Thanks for clarifying this. One last thing can you help me in making this query execute using sp_executesql?

Comment: @SandeepPolavarapu Do you really need that? The values you have in `#PropertyPath` is just values in nodes and you do not need dynamic SQL to find those.

Comment: Yes, i need to extract text in value node of xml. For example #PropertyPath has RollNumber which is a name node in XML, i need to get its value 2127 which is value node in XML. Do you think we dont need dynamic SQL? if not then what is the way?

Comment: @SandeepPolavarapu That is what you do in the first query.

Comment: my first query gives 2127 if i insert a Value instead of Name into #PropertyPath. But i am looking at something inserting RollNumber,StudentName and Subject1 in #PropertyPath i need to get 2127, ABCD, 80 so that i can relate them

Comment: @SandeepPolavarapu I have updated the answer with a query. Try it and see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikael Eriksson, you are the best :)